# R: nlevels for a part of the column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe. I have many different research plots and I want to know the amount of species I have in each plot. I use to find all species I found `nlevels(df$Sp)`, so from my understanding `nlevels(df$Sp[df$Pl=="1"])` should be able to give me the amount of species in only the first plot. But it gives me the same amount. What am I missing?

Comment: `factor` column doesn't drop its levels upon sub-setting. Either wrap the subset into `factor` or `droplevels` or just replace `nlevels` with `length(unique())`.

Comment: `levels(factor(c("a","b"))[1])` still returns both `a` and `b` - this is by design. You want to know what possibilities there are for a factor regardless of subsetting.

Comment: Thank you all, `length(unique))` worked perfectly.